# Android Gridview with a external scrollbar

Tags: android, gridview, scroll, contacts

I have a gridview with some objects inside it and I have an alphabetic list that is compose by a lof of textviews.

I want to click on "A" and the gridview is going down until the letter "A" and  the same with the other letters.

Maybe that won't be a problem but the big problem is when I scrolling the gridview, I want to know which items are display and try to get the first item to decide which letter is it.

That look like the iphone contact

Answer (score 0):

There's a very similar situation addressed here:

[How to implement scrollbar with thumb for fast scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957172/how-to-implement-scrollbar-with-thumb-for-fast-scrolling)

I'm pretty sure that's exactly what you want.