# Custom Listview Fast Scrollbar in android

Tags: android

I want to custom a listview with a touchable fast scrollbar like Google play music app with vertical line with thumb image. It provides an easy and fast way to scroll with this touchable fast scrollbar. I tried searching for custom scrollbar like this, but I couldn't find any with fast scrollbar in listview. I am expecting the output of the scrollbar like the below figure:

[image]

The fast scrollbar outside is marked in red line. I have found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171755/custom-scrollbar-android) on StackOverflow, but the code in the link doesn't give me the expected output. Can you help me do this?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Finally, I came up with a solution. It only works with **API level 11 or higher**

**values/style.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
        <item name="android:fastScrollThumbDrawable">@drawable/fast_thumb</item>
        <item name="android:fastScrollTrackDrawable">@drawable/fastscroll_track_default_holo_dark</item>

</style>
```

Apply activity for this theme like below code:

```
         <activity
            android:name="com.example.viewpager.FirstActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Activity layout XML like below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rlScrollingPlayList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
            android:fastScrollAlwaysVisible="true"
            android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Resource **image files** are

[image] [image] [image: enter here]

Fast scroll thumb selector XML file:

**drawable/fast_thumb.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/fastscroll_thumb_pressed_holo"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/fastscroll_thumb_default_holo"></item>

</selector>
```

Final output like below figure:

[image]

Comment: In the case someone would need to remove FastScrollTrackDrawable >>  <item name="android:fastScrollTrackDrawable">@null</item>

Comment: nice answer, however selector is not working in my case.

Answer (score 2):

so for android api level < 11 there is special hack

```
// special hack for violet fast scroll
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            try {
                java.lang.reflect.Field f = AbsListView.class.getDeclaredField("mFastScroller");
                f.setAccessible(true);
                Object o = f.get(root.findViewById(R.id.beam_contact_listview));
                f = f.getType().getDeclaredField("mThumbDrawable");
                f.setAccessible(true);
                Drawable drawable = (Drawable) f.get(o);
                drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sv_fastscroll);
                f.set(o, drawable);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

this code plus solution for android api level >= 11 = solution for all android api levels )