# android listview auto hide custom fast scroll thumb

Tags: android, android-listview

is it possible to hide custom thumb while not scrolling
, i use this post for custom fast scroll 
[Custom Listview Fast Scrollbar in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17337182/custom-listview-fast-scrollbar-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove android:fastScrollAlwaysVisible attribute or set it to false.

You can also do it programmatically using [setFastScrollAlwaysVisible](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setFastScrollAlwaysVisible(boolean))

Answer (score 0):

```
android:fastScrollAlwaysVisible="false"
```

Comment: Please, provide some explanation of your suggestion.